# SQL Server - Compound key of a table and restarted to one each year

Tags: sql-server, database, key

I'd like to know how to create a key compound for orders that have the year and the order number of that year. I'm working with SQL Server.

As an example:

```
2015-1
2015-2
2015-3
[...]
2015-598

2016-1
2016-2
[...]
2016-896

2017-1
2017-2
2017-3
[...]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The effort is not worth the trouble. For display purposes, you can easily dynamically generate this representation from a single numerically increasing surrogate key without creating a composite key as you describe. Plus, the dynamically generated expression will automatically account for inserted and deleted rows in the sequence, whereas keeping a persisted composite key accurate would be another headache.

Answer (score 0):

> row_number() over(partition by year(.....)